# Grammar checker for html text area

Tags: javascript, python, php, html, textarea

In my HTML and PHP code, I have a textarea in which I want to be able to see if the text has any spelling or grammar errors. I am ready to use Python or Javascript to make this possible too! Looking for help.

Comment: Personally I would not bother, how often do you click ignore in word when it thinks you have made such an error?

Comment: Sapling can show edits directly on the textarea: https://sapling.ai/docs/sdk/HTML/quickstart

Or you can programmatically get text areas with the HTTP API: https://sapling.ai/programming-language/php

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sounds like [LanguageTool](http://wiki.languagetool.org/public-http-api) is what you need. They have a nice API, but keep in mind it is limited to 20 requests per IP address per minute. If you need more, they have a how-to on [setting it up locally](https://dev.languagetool.org/http-server).